# Highcharts tooltip looks weird

Tags: javascript, highcharts

**Update (2016.03.03): I'm using Safari v9.0.3 and Chrome v48.0.2564.116 on Mac OS X 10.11.3. I can't replicate the issue to jsfiddle to show. Actually, I've found the issue may disappear after I refresh the pages, so I don't think it's caused by my additional JavaScript or CSS files.**

I'm working with Highcharts these days and I've run into a problem that the tooltip of my basic line graph looks weird.

The tooltips of some points look normal like below: 
[image]

However, tooltips of the other points look different like: 
[image]

I can tell no differences between two DOM trees rendered...

And I tried my code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iplus26/Lxhb496o/) but it looks fine...

```
There's no code, check out the jsfiddle link above
```

I don't know why it's different, any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which browser do you use? How we can replicate your issue if jsfiddle works well? Maybe you have any additonal CSS / Javascript which overwrite Highcharts behaviour?

Comment: @SebastianBochan Check out the update pls~

Comment: Thnaks for that, but unforunatley withotu any live demo is a difficult ot debug.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please post your highcharts code? That will help to diagnose the issue, and provide a more substantial solution.

Also, I would suggest setting the useHTML option to true in case that is causing any issues.  Here is a link on how you can do that: [useHTML](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.useHTML)

This will allow the chart renderer to read all html elements within your tooltip formatter function, instead of just a subset of html elements. I have seen this cause issues in the past when people try to incorporate fancy code into their tooltip.

Not sure if that will fix your issue, but it's a good place to start.

Comment: `useHTML` seems to work! i'll accept your answer if there's no more this problem in a few hours~Thx!

Comment: The problem still exist... Tried `useHTML` and the dom trees look the same.. jsfiddle link added but it works fine in it... So weird

Comment: Try testing in different browsers to see if the issue is browser specific.  Also, is the console throwing any errors when you see the issue?

Comment: I tried in both Safari and Chrome on my Mac and Chrome on Windows. There is no error in the console.

Comment: Not sure what else we can do without being able to replicate the error.  Does it happen on the same point every time?  Does it happen whenever a certain character is used?  If you remove the non-latin characters does that work?  Any help narrowing down possible causes would help.

Comment: Sorry, I understand that it's almost impossible to locate the error without being able to replicate it. I've tried to move the non-latin characters or decrease the length of the text but no luck.